# TortoiseSVNのコマンドラインでリネームする方法

Tags: svn

TortoiseSVNのTortoiseProcを利用してファイルの拡張子を一律リネームしようとしていますが、リネーム後のファイル名を指定するオプションがわかりません。以下の例でいうとtest.txtをtest.batにリネームしてコミットしようとしています。

```
D:\test_repo>TortoiseProc /command:rename /path:D:\test_repo\test.txt test.bat /noquestion
```

[付録D TortoiseSVN の自動化](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_ja/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics)を見ると出来そうなのですが、新しい名前を入力するダイアログを表示させずに処理するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。ご教示願います。

> /path で指定されたファイルの名前を変更します。このファイルの新しい名前を入力するダイアログが表示されます。一度に同様のファイルの名前の変更を行う際、確認を行わないようにするには、 /noquestion を指定してください。

Comment: TortoiseProcを使わなければ駄目ですか？今のところGUIを使わない方法は無いようです。TortoiseSVNの開発者用フォーラム(英語)で[renameに/path2オプションが欲しい](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn-dev/I1yOHIWp7ZY)という要望が上がっていたようですが、自動化するならTortoiseSVNにも同梱されている`svn.exe`を使った方がいいという返事が返されていました。

Comment: ここ [how to use svn copy / svn rename commands in windows bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327258/how-to-use-svn-copy-svn-rename-commands-in-windows-bat-file) などを見ますと、必ずダイアログが表示されてしまう様です。回答にある様にコマンドラインで使うことができる svn クライアントコマンドを使って処理する方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseProc.exeでは行えないです。代替えとして、svn.exeを利用することによって実現可能でした。
ご回答ありがとうございます。

```
svn rename CURR_PATH NEW_PATH
```

参照：[TortoiseSVNのコマンド](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_ja/tsvn-cli-main.html)